# QMessageBox warning yellow exclamation mark icon

Tags: qt, warnings, qmessagebox

How is possible to display a `QMessageBox::warning` with the triangular exclamation mark symbol like the one following?

[image: Yellow background triangular exclamation mark]

I can't find any option in `QMessageBox::warning`, I only get the red circular symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangular icon should be the default for the `QMessageBox::warning` dialog, while the red circular one is the default for the `QMessageBox::critical` dialog.

In my python code I use either

`QMessageBox.warning(None,QString("..."),QString("...."))`

or the more complex

```
msg = "..."
q = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Warning, "...",  QString(msg))
q.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok);
i = QIcon()
i.addPixmap(QPixmap("..."), QIcon.Normal)
q.setWindowIcon(i)
q.exec_()
```

And both of them works well.

Eventually can you show the code you use to show the dialog ?

Comment: QMessageBox::warning( this,  "This is a warning", "Problem somewhere" );

in Linux with Qt 4.7.3 I get the red circular exclamation mark, but on Windows the triangular yellow one.

Comment: I can only confirm that under linux works both with python and C++, but I have installed only the 4.8.1 version. Sorry...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the QMessageBox.setIcon() function to configure which symbol you see when the dialog is displayed.

The predefined icon property types are listed here:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#severity-levels-and-the-icon-and-pixmap-properties

Here is my C++ example of a message box with the yellow triangle icon:

```
    QMessageBox msgWarning;
    msgWarning.setText("WARNING!\nRunning low on coffee.");
    msgWarning.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    msgWarning.setWindowTitle("Caution");
    msgWarning.exec();
```

And here is my C++ example of a message box with the red circle icon:

```
    QMessageBox msgError;
    msgError.setText("CRITICAL ERROR!\nThe McRib is no longer available!");
    msgError.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
    msgError.setWindowTitle("Danger");
    msgError.exec();
```